# how to convert image from file path to bitmap in c#

Tags: c#

```
Bitmap  bmp = new Bitmap("D:\1.jpg");
```

The exception I get  is:

> parameter is not valid.

How can I solve this?

Comment: backslashes: \n forms a newline. escape them by doubling them, or put an @ in front of the string literal.

Answer (score 7):

That usually just works, are you using an escape character to escape the escape character? 
Example:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap("D:\\newfolder\\1.jpg");
//Notice the \\ the second \ escapes the first
```

Or escape it like this:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(@"D:\newfolder\1.jpg");
//Notice the @ in front of the string, that means ignore the escape characters
```

Your original string doesn't escape this and thus inserts a newline (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Image.FromFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
try
{
    Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\" +
        @"All Users\Documents\My Music\music.bmp", true);

}
catch(System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error opening the bitmap." +
        "Please check the path.");
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with using `Bitmap(String)` - string being the file path? Just curious

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the *constructor*, or using Image.FromFile. The OP though forgot to escape ` \`

Comment: @FakeCaleb Nothing really. My answer is over engineered, for the use case. EpicKip's answer would be most suitable.

Comment: @HarrisonPerry Yeah that's what I thought, just a curious question. Nothing more